# Using SSL certificate issue?

Tags: php, ssl, https, hosting

My hosting account has two folders for me to upload/installing websites onto:

1. /httpdocs/
2. /httpsdocs/

I have installed phpMyDirectory into /httpdocs/ and all works great. I have since purchased a SSL certificate and my webhost has installed this for me on my domain. My issue arises when I insert the base url for SSL in the default.php (settings file) as such:

```
$BASE_URL_SSL = 'https://www.mydomain.com';
```

I realise the problem is that I don't have my website installed in the HTTPS secure directory on my hosting account. Do I copy the content from /httpdocs/ to /httpsdocs/ or should I make a fresh installation only in the /httpsdocs/ directory?

Comment: The easiest solution is to ask your hosting company to set it up to mirror the folders.  Easy for them to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard solutions are to either

1. [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink) the necessary directories/files into the https directory, or
2. use .htaccess rules to rewrite from the https directory to the http directory.

Which to use depends on what possibilities your host gives you.